# Declaring ajax API wrecks page formatting

Tags: jquery, ajax, formatting

First off, I'm not a web programmer so this may seem trivial. I have a dynamic website that works fine using jquery. But simply declaring the following script:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

wrecks the list and text formatting called by the textillate.js library, which in turn requires:

```
<script src="scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/lettering.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/textillate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I don't do anything with ...3.3.1/jquery.min.js - it's presence alone is enough to override hitherto OK formatting. Is it that I can't have jquery.js + jquery.min.js? Is what I want, which is to create new div elements and text content, already handled by the jquery.js library anyway?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks in advance, and have a good one.

Peter

Comment: You don't need jquery.js and jquery.min.js - especially if they're different jquery versions. Pick one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before using textillate or before including its library try using jquery's noConflict as seen here https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/ Alternatively, if you can... don't bother including
`<script src="scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

The .min.js should be sufficient.